# Tkinter - default colour in colorchooser

Tags: python, tkinter

In the colorchooser dialog I would like to set a default colour in the chooser that it sets the colour to first, instead of the grey colour.

```
self.colour = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]
```

The current way it is set out is:

[image]

But it would be good if the default in the bottom right was a different colour. I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
colorchooser.askcolor('#ffd9d9')
```

or simpler

```
colorchooser.askcolor('red')
```

or even

```
colorchooser.askcolor((10,20,30))
```